# How can I reference jenkinsfile declarative tools reference in my code

Tags: jenkins

I have a section at the top of my jenkinsfile for tools that manages the installation.  I want to see if I can reference this values later on in my declarative code.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'buildfarm' }
    options { buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '15')) }
    tools {
        maven '3.6.2'
        jdk 'jdk9'
    }
```

When I generate code for the pipeline it given me code like this ...

```
 withMaven( maven: 'Maven 3.5.0 Linux', globalMavenSettingsConfig:
            'f0b3bb88-e3b7-4ba2-a1b5-8a5ab8ce02fc', mavenLocalRepo:
             '.repository'){
        sh "mvn clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
 }
```

This code resides in a library and I want the values in the tools section of the Jenkinsfile to be able to set the values for maven version in the library declarative code.  Is this possible and how?

Comment: You cannot modify the library function on-the-fly in your pipeline. Either you need to update the library function itself to accept the maven version as an argument and parameterize it, for example, `withMaven( maven: maven, globalMavenSettingsConfig: ...)` or reuse the code in your pipeline without invoking the library function.